# LINQ weak relation between tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have two tables with a weak relation.
I need get a text value from one table using a key from another.
I am using the following C# LINQ code:

```
City = rea.tRealEstateContact.tPostnumre != null ? rea.tRealEstateContact.tPostnumre.Bynavn : string.Empty
```

But when the key cannot be found in the table 1(tPostnumre), an exception is thrown.

How should I do this?

Comment: By weak relation do you mean that one does not have a primary key?

Comment: Yes it is. I have only values what may be exist in other table, where it is Primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't there a tPostnumreID  in the RealEstateContact table that's used to link to tPostnumre?

```
 City = rea.tRealEstateContact.tPostnumreID != null ?
          rea.tRealEstateContact.tPostnumre.Bynavn : string.Empty
```